# Show table content from PHP to android table

Tags: android

i have this high score board in http://drymvizion.atwebpages.com/ and i want a simple way to click a button and show this content in my android application without opening browser. I am a bit new in android developing and i hope it's easy. Thanks ;)

Comment: you should provide sample code that you have tried so far. do not expect others to do the work for you.

Comment: i dont ask for code, i ask which is the best way so i try to find info and start coding this. i know how to open in pop up browser but of course it's not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a HttpGet request to get the contents, or better use a xml parser, such as JSoup. For example:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("site.name");
try 
{
    get.addHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String result = "";
    while ((result = rd.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        Log.e("HttpResponse", result);
        if (result.length() > 0)
        {
            // do something with the source                 
        }
    }
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WebView's

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html